# Might an input with the form attribute precede the form element in the document?

Tags: html, forms

In a generated page, it would be easiest if some of the inputs preceded the form definition.  The `form` attribute seems to be the appropriate mechanism (eg `<input form='f1' ...>`.  In the examples I found online, the form precedes the inputs, so I am wondering if it is OK for these input elements to precede the form in the document as in:

```
<input form='f1' type='text' name='i1'>
   ...
<form id='f1' action='...'>
<input type='submit' name='s2'>
</form>
```

In my (limited) testing this seems to work, but I can not find wording in the standard that requires it to work.   In particular, the [standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-formelements-form) says:

> If a reassociateable form-associated element has a form attribute specified, then that attribute’s value must be the ID of a form element in the element’s owner Document.

And at the time the input element is encountered in the document, there is (not yet) any such form.  Am I reading this incorrectly?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-form

Comment: I assume you are referring to "The form attribute lets you place an input anywhere in the document but have it included with a form elsewhere in the document."  I take that as describing the Mozilla behavior.  My question is does the standard require it.

Comment: If you don't use the attribute, the field will not be included in the submit action, so it would be required.

Comment: I thought `[name]` was required for submit of values, `[form]` attribute isn't a requirement. How the words are written *"can"*, *"may"*, *"feature"* etc. infer the opposite. It sasy: [*"This feature allows authors to work around the lack of support for nested form elements."*](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms)

Comment: As far as recall, the fact that the form does not exist yet in the document doesn't matter, because  on adding the form, the ["reset the form owner"](https://w3c.github.io/html/sec-forms.html#reset-the-form-owner) of the control algorithm gets run, to complete the assignment. This is true regardless of whether the form is added by the parser, or later by JS, or even if JS changes the id of a form. Similarly, if a form gets deleted. Unsurprisingly, there's not a single, simple quote from the spec that covers all that.

Comment: @zer00ne I know that the form attribute is not required, using it makes my process which generates the HTML in question simpler.  My question is, am I allowed to put such `<input form='xxx' ...>`s *before* the `<form id='xxx' ...>` that they reference or must they follow it.

Comment: @JohnHascall sorry my last comment was directed to D-JM's comment. I believe Alohci's point to be the best advice, just because it isn't documented doesn't mean it ain't so. Your concerns need a higher degree of detail, I suggest that you refer to the [*Living Standards - 4.10.17.3 Association of controls and forms*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#association-of-controls-and-forms). When you weave through all of the applicable links, keep in mind what is inferred as well as what is implied.... *(continued)*

Comment: ... *(continued)* From what I get from reading both specs is that if a form control is on the document -- nested within a form or not -- the form attribute will associate said form control to the form on the same document with an id that matches the value of the form attribute. Being on the same document implies before, after, or within a form element -- anywhere.

Comment: I agree that this statement there: "If element is listed, has a form content attribute, and is connected, then:

If the first element in element's tree, in tree order, to have an ID that is case-sensitively equal to element's form content attribute's value, is a form element, then associate the element with that form element." establishes that once the `<form>` is encounter in the document the `<input>` is associated with it.  I wanted the standard to say that at the time of encountering `<input form=id>` it is not an error if the form of that id is not yet known, it simply uses null.

Comment: Anyway, if you would turn your comments into an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks.